# How to save data correctly

Tags: sqlite, indexing, save, relationship

I want to store data in SQLite database, but I am not sure which option is correct to use.

I want to store information about computers. Each computer has a specific color.

**The problem is: Should I save colors into another table and match them to computers via relationship or can I just save colors as integer value and write to documentation assignments color to index (that integer value).**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the usage of the db, but if it is a school task or something like that: Make a color-table.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite with the correct version appears to support foreign keys (http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html), therefore, you should create a separate table for the colors so you don't have to store the same color every time. In my opinion it would be more efficient, especially if you think the same colors will appear multiple times.

A color for each entry would be 4+4+4 bytes for the red blue green components.  Where an ID to refer to the color for each computer would only be 2 bytes (or at most 4 bytes) if your ids start to go past 65,535~ (2 byte integer).

So you can save a lot of memory by creating a foreign key relationship to the colors.